# Pgfplots stops plot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the function

```
(0.5*x+1)^(-2)
```

for x in [0,6].

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
      thick,
      axis lines = center,
      axis line style={->},
      xmin = 0, xmax = 6.1,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 1.1,
      restrict y to domain = 0:1,
      xlabel = {$t$}, ylabel = {$\phi(t)$},
      xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
      ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
      ]
      \addplot[no marks, 
               thick,
               samples = 200,
               ] expression {(0.5*x+1)^(-2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: Problematic plot]

The problem is that the plot stops after x = 5. Also for x = 0, the function value should be 1. This doesn't seem to be the case in my plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the domain in the `x` direction; the default is `domain=-5:5` (see page 54 of the v1.12 manual). Explicitly setting the domain in the plot options fixes this. The other problem at `x=0` is fixed by increasing the number of samples. The following code should fix both problems:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
      thick,
      axis lines = center,
      axis line style={->},
      xmin = 0, xmax = 6.1,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 1.1,
      % restrict y to domain = 0:1,
      xlabel = {$t$}, ylabel = {$\phi(t)$},
      xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
      ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
      ]
      \addplot[no marks, 
               thick,
               samples = 1000,
               domain=0:6] expression {(0.5*x+1)^(-2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]